# Using BeautifulSoup to find all links and group by link target (href)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the `BeautifulSoup` package to parse an HTML body to search for all `<a>` tags. What I am trying to do is gather all links, and group them by the `<a>` target (href).

For example: if `http://www.google.com` is listed twice in the HTML body, then I need to group the links together and list the `<a>`'s `data-name` attribute. (`data-name` is something added in by my editor for when the user names their link(s)).

```
def extract_links_from_mailing(mailing):
    content = "%s %s" % (mailing.html_body, mailing.plaintext)
    pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
    links = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")

    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if not link.get('no_track'):
            target = link.get('href')
            name = link.get('data-name')
            link_text = unicode(link)

            if any([
                not target,
                'example.net' in target,
                target.startswith('mailto'),
                '{' in target,
                target.startswith('#')
            ]):
                continue

            target = pattern.search(target)

            # found a target and the target isn't already apart of the list
            if target and not any(l['target'] == target.group() for l in links):
                links.append({
                    'name': name,
                    'target': target.group()
                })

    return links
```

The above output looks like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Goog 1",
        "target": "https://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Yahoo!",
        "target": "http://www.yahoo.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Goog 2",
        "target": "https://www.google.com"
    }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
[
    {
        "target": "https://www.google.com",
        "names": ["Goog 1", "Goog 2"]
    },
    {
        "target": "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "names": ["Yahoo!"]
    },
]
```

Comment: Is the order of targets important?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the targets:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

links = defaultdict(set)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    ...

    if target:
        links[target.group()].add(name)
```

As a result, `links` would contain a dictionary where the keys would be `target`s and values - sets of `name`s.

Comment: Where does the `list` variable get set?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz this is a built-in `list` keyword.

Comment: Im getting this error: `"error": "'_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable"`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz oops, sure, fixed.

Comment: I changed it to that and now I am getting `string indices must be integer`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz replaced the uniqueness check with a `defaultdict(set)`, check it out.

Comment: So, I changed it to your suggestion and changed my `return` value to be `return list(links)` (was getting that `sets` aren't JSON serializable). But now the output is just a list of all of the target href's and no names

Comment: @dennismonsewicz nono, when you call `list(links)` - you are just getting a list of keys - targets.

Comment: Oops my mistake... changed it back and am now getting this error: `set([u'HTTP Goog']) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz what are you trying to do with `links` afterwards? Thanks.

Comment: I am returning them as an API endpoint in an application I am building

Comment: @dennismonsewicz you need to learn how to dump the structure with sets inside into JSON, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/python-sets-are-not-json-serializable.

Comment: After thinking about this, I am going to need the API endpoint to return a list of objects that contain a `target` attribute and a `names` attribute