# Python request.post Not Accepting Dictionary

Tags: python, api, request

here is the data that I want to post,

this is the printed version of the dictionary answers:

```
{'Emails': set([u'vernon.fadel@denesik.com', u'helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com', u'tryan@fishercremin.com', u'cecilia.kerluke@gmail.com', u'sonia.ruecker@schmidt.info', u'reichel.tamatha@gmail.com', u'johntyree69@greendale.edu', u'gail34@reichel.com', u'birdman@quitzon.net ', u'onolan@gmail.com', u'lindgren.merry@howe.com', u'wilderman.nyree@heidenreich.com', u'yschneider@jacobson.biz', u'nakia.larkin@gmail.com', u'vblanda@gmail.com', u'pkoch@yahoo.com', u'ygoyette@yahoo.com', u'wiegand.lynnette@beer.com', u'ubradtke@hotmail.com', u'troy67@yahoo.com', u'eileen.gusikowski@oreilly.info', u'glubowitz@yahoo.com', u'inolan@hotmail.com', u'lfranecki@hotmail.com', u'miller.hana@gmail.com', u'morissette.lalla@kuhicmuller.com', u'harber.gisele@gmail.com', u'odalys.dubuque@ebertrunte.net', u'jones.kyree@auer.net', u'adams77@yahoo.com', u'parisian.linda@hotmail.com', u'channing.cremin@toy.org', u'chad.armstrong@yahoo.com', u'isaac.nolan@hotmail.com', u'kozey.luciana@collins.biz', u'cstehr@keebler.com', u'jquitzon@gmail.com', u'hhirthe@yahoo.com', u'emilia16@block.com', u'arice@greenholtconsidine.com', u'tobin.schuppe@gmail.com', u'wyman.junious@gmail.com', u'mrath@ruecker.com ', u' johns.sonji@lakinwalker.info', u'thiel.cassie@hodkiewicz.info', u'fjaskolski@hotmail.com', u'mosciski.destany@hotmail.com', u'vrippin@gmail.com', u'zschuppe@hotmail.com', u'clotilda26@goodwinlind.info', u'lizette.walker@stanton.com', u'hettinger.kamari@hotmail.com', u'emelia54@yahoo.com', u'terry.ezekiel@hotmail.com', u'douglyass.dickinson@hotmail.com', u'zulauf.olympia@gmail.com', u'maxxx.waters@sauer.biz', u'abshire.charmaine@schusterlabadie.com', u'kuvalis.dewitt@wolfschaefer.com', u"elberta.o'connell@yahoo.com", u'henery76@yahoo.com', u'britny60@gmail.com', u'ed.hilpert@hansen.com', u'burnice.feest@yahoo.com', u' ybartoletti@littel.biz', u'sharde.murazik@hotmail.com', u'angelica.klocko@ankunding', u'brandi.klein@hotmail.com', u'dollie49@hotmail.com', u'mrath@ruecker.com', u'hayley27@koelpin.com', u'georgiann.mertz@moen.net', u'floretta39@volkmanrosenbaum.net', u'vicy.predovic@gmail.com', u'raven53@yahoo.com', u'fmann@yahoo.com', u'sdaugherty@gmail.com', u'gerlach.villa@koelpinfeeney.net', u'alysha.gibson@hotmail.com', u'hoy.kozey@gmail.com', u'cheyenne84@lehneroconner.com', u'uoberbrunner@hotmail.com', u'hhaag@swaniawskiterry.info', u'infant80@yahoo.com', u'manilla.west@hotmail.com', u'hconsidine@bernhardhills.info', u'dean94@hotmail.com', u'bahringer.karl@yahoo.com', u'crona.meredith@gmail.com', u'letta.larkin@quitzon.net', u'owindler@strosin.info', u'shanahan.anders@yahoo.com', u'mclaughlin.desi@gmail.com', u'erdman.icy@hotmail.com', u'salvatore21@hintz.com', u'jkoch@hotmail.com', u'red.beatty@yahoo.com', u'helma91@hotmail.com', u'arland.koepp@hotmail.com', u'ymoore@cristhalvorson.org', u'woodie.crooks@kozey.com', None, u'jchamplin@hotmail.com ', u'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com']), '# of Emails per Domain': {u'@hotmail.com': 22, u'@yahoo.com': 18, u'@gmail.com': 18}, 'April Users': 70}
```

when I run:

```
 r = requests.post('https://9g9xhayrh5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/data', data = answers)
```

I get this error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'Emails\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@311a7237; line: 1, column: 8]"}
```

Not sure what this means at all, I've tried to parse the data into json, why doesn't it like the 'Email' string?

If I add the json.dump code I get:

```
TypeError

TypeError: set([u'vernon.fadel@denesik.com', u'helyn67@cruickshankmckenzie.com', u'tryan@fishercremin.com', u'cecilia.kerluke@gmail.com', u'sonia.ruecker@schmidt.info', u'reichel.tamatha@gmail.com', u'johntyree69@greendale.edu', u'gail34@reichel.com', u'birdman@quitzon.net ', u'onolan@gmail.com', u'lindgren.merry@howe.com', u'wilderman.nyree@heidenreich.com', u'yschneider@jacobson.biz', u'nakia.larkin@gmail.com', u'vblanda@gmail.com', u'pkoch@yahoo.com', u'ygoyette@yahoo.com', u'wiegand.lynnette@beer.com', u'ubradtke@hotmail.com', u'troy67@yahoo.com', u'eileen.gusikowski@oreilly.info', u'glubowitz@yahoo.com', u'inolan@hotmail.com', u'lfranecki@hotmail.com', u'miller.hana@gmail.com', u'morissette.lalla@kuhicmuller.com', u'harber.gisele@gmail.com', u'odalys.dubuque@ebertrunte.net', u'jones.kyree@auer.net', u'adams77@yahoo.com', u'parisian.linda@hotmail.com', u'channing.cremin@toy.org', u'chad.armstrong@yahoo.com', u'isaac.nolan@hotmail.com', u'kozey.luciana@collins.biz', u'cstehr@keebler.com', u'jquitzon@gmail.com', u'hhirthe@yahoo.com', u'emilia16@block.com', u'arice@greenholtconsidine.com', u'tobin.schuppe@gmail.com', u'wyman.junious@gmail.com', u'mrath@ruecker.com ', u' johns.sonji@lakinwalker.info', u'thiel.cassie@hodkiewicz.info', u'fjaskolski@hotmail.com', u'mosciski.destany@hotmail.com', u'vrippin@gmail.com', u'zschuppe@hotmail.com', u'clotilda26@goodwinlind.info', u'lizette.walker@stanton.com', u'hettinger.kamari@hotmail.com', u'emelia54@yahoo.com', u'terry.ezekiel@hotmail.com', u'douglyass.dickinson@hotmail.com', u'zulauf.olympia@gmail.com', u'maxxx.waters@sauer.biz', u'abshire.charmaine@schusterlabadie.com', u'kuvalis.dewitt@wolfschaefer.com', u"elberta.o'connell@yahoo.com", u'henery76@yahoo.com', u'britny60@gmail.com', u'ed.hilpert@hansen.com', u'burnice.feest@yahoo.com', u' ybartoletti@littel.biz', u'sharde.murazik@hotmail.com', u'angelica.klocko@ankunding', u'brandi.klein@hotmail.com', u'dollie49@hotmail.com', u'mrath@ruecker.com', u'hayley27@koelpin.com', u'georgiann.mertz@moen.net', u'floretta39@volkmanrosenbaum.net', u'vicy.predovic@gmail.com', u'raven53@yahoo.com', u'fmann@yahoo.com', u'sdaugherty@gmail.com', u'gerlach.villa@koelpinfeeney.net', u'alysha.gibson@hotmail.com', u'hoy.kozey@gmail.com', u'cheyenne84@lehneroconner.com', u'uoberbrunner@hotmail.com', u'hhaag@swaniawskiterry.info', u'infant80@yahoo.com', u'manilla.west@hotmail.com', u'hconsidine@bernhardhills.info', u'dean94@hotmail.com', u'bahringer.karl@yahoo.com', u'crona.meredith@gmail.com', u'letta.larkin@quitzon.net', u'owindler@strosin.info', u'shanahan.anders@yahoo.com', u'mclaughlin.desi@gmail.com', u'erdman.icy@hotmail.com', u'salvatore21@hintz.com', u'jkoch@hotmail.com', u'red.beatty@yahoo.com', u'helma91@hotmail.com', u'arland.koepp@hotmail.com', u'ymoore@cristhalvorson.org', u'woodie.crooks@kozey.com', None, u'jchamplin@hotmail.com ', u'walter.elwyn@yahoo.com']) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: JSON doesn't know `set`. Also, you should definitely not post these email adresses here.

Comment: I'm assuming these are fake, but good call

Comment: Try `answers['Emails'] = list(answers['Emails'])`.

Comment: same error unrecognized token 'Email'

Comment: Ok interesting, what do you mean by that? Sorry I'm very new to Python

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, but I resolved it now: It works if you encode the JSON yourself and hand `requests.post` a JSON-encoded string as the `data` parameter.

Comment: See my answer for why it didn't work before :)

Comment: You appear to have posted a number of emails in this question, which is often accidental. If this is the case, please edit your question so it doesn't contain any sensitive information and then flag it so we can get the revision history cleaned out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `TypeError: set([ ... ]) is not JSON serializable`

*Sets are not JSON serializable*. You can either convert all of the sets to lists in the dictionary:

```
answers = {key: list(value) if isinstance(value, set) else value
           for key, value in answers.items()}
```

<sup>(Note that this would not work for nested dictionaries as is).</sup>

Or, use a [custom JSON encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230505/771848) that would handle the set serialization.

---

Dumping and loading it back with `json` usually helps in debugging:

```
import json

answers = json.loads(json.dumps(answers))
r = requests.post('https://9g9xhayrh5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/data', data=answers)
```

Comment: good suggestion, I tried that method but I'm getting a TypeError

Comment: @AdamWeitzman please post the traceback, this might give us a clue what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamWeitzman yup, exactly, updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: hmmm tried to do it manually with no luck, i'll try the JSON encoding

Comment: @AdamWeitzman yeah, cause you have other sets in the dictionary, updated the first option. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
import requests
import json
answers = {} #...
url = "..."
answers['Emails'] = list(answers['Emails'])
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(answers))
```

The reason the other way doesn't work is that by default requests sends data with the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.

To change that, you can also use `json` instead of the `data` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=answers)
```

---

To debug code using the requests library, you can [look at a prepared request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/1016216) before sending it.