# Writing a set to an output file in python

Tags: python, file, set, output

I usually use json for lists, but it doesn't work for sets. Is there a similar function to write a set into an output file,f? Something like this, but for sets:

```
f=open('kos.txt','w')
json.dump(list, f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`json` is not a python-specific format. It knows about lists and dictionaries, but not sets or tuples.

But if you want to persist a pure python dataset you could use string conversion.

```
with open('kos.txt','w') as f:
   f.write(str({1,3,(3,5)}))  # set of numbers & a tuple
```

then read it back again using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
with open('kos.txt','r') as f:
   my_set = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

this also works for lists of sets, nested lists with sets inside... as long as the data can be evaluated literally and *no sets are empty* (a [known limitation](https://bugs.python.org/issue24663) of `literal_eval`). So basically serializing (almost) any python basic object structure with `str` can be parsed back with it.

For the empty set case there's a kludge to apply since `set()` cannot be parsed back.

```
import ast
with open('kos.txt','r') as f:
   ser = f.read()
my_set = set() if ser == str(set()) else ast.literal_eval(ser)
```

You could also have used the `pickle` module, but it creates binary data, so more "opaque", and there's also a way to use `json`: [How to JSON serialize sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/python-sets-are-not-json-serializable). But for your needs, I would stick to `str/ast.literal_eval`

Comment: This solution will give `ValueError: malformed node or string:` at `ast.literal_eval(f.read())`, if there is empty set.

Comment: `str(set())` yields `set()` so yes, it doesn't work with an empty set. Some hack would be possible, though, checking for `set()` and replacing by an empty set

Answer (score 9):

Using `ast.literal_eval(f.read())` will give error `ValueError: malformed node or string`, if we write empty set in file. I think, `pickle` would be better to use.

If set is empty, this will give no error.

```
import pickle

s = set()

##To save in file
with open('kos.txt','wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(s, f)

##To read it again from file
with open('kos.txt','rb') as f:
   my_set = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: I already mentionned `pickle` in my solution. The only interesting feature is the empty set case, that can be emulated (discussed here: https://bugs.python.org/issue24663). otherwise pickle drawback is ... all the rest (impossible to edit, binary format...)