# what kind of error str brings in when it can't deal with conversion?

Tags: python, json, jsonconvert

I am writing a kind of 'universal' json decoder that would convert everything it can using a default json encoder plus sets, and everything else it will convert using `str()` - which is a bit stupid, but it will allow to just work silently and let users know what kind of data there was initially.

So with the small amendment the following code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230505/1334752):

```
import json
class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, set):
            return list(obj)
        try:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        except TypeError:
            return str(obj)
```

Then if I try to convert a function using this encoder it will return something like:

```
'<function a at 0x10ddd8f28>'
```

Which is, again a bit stupid but totally fine for my purposes.

**The question is:** what if `str()` fails to convert anything provided as an input argument? What kind of error will be triggered? I looked through `str` source and didn't get when exactly (if at all?) it captures the possible conversion errors. Or it is assumed to convert any kind of input provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the documentation of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> If neither encoding nor errors is given, `str(object)` returns `object.__str__()`, which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a `__str__()` method, then `str()` falls back to returning `repr(object)`.

That said. Besides situations like not being able allocate any more memory (`MemoryError`) which would not be `str` conversion specific, the only way I can see this failing is if someone overloaded `__str__` (or `__repr__` if there is no `__str__`) and made it to, for instance:

```
class C:
    def __str__(self):
        msg = "'{}' instance is not meant to be represented as str."
        raise ValueError(msg.format(self.__class__))
```

Which would result in:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> str(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __str__
ValueError: '<class '__main__.C'>' instance is not meant to be represented as str.
```

That said though: There isn't really a generic answer to your question, because it could raise anything anyone programmed it to do.

EDIT: All of above pertains to simple `str` calls with just an object passed as seen in your example. If you attempt decoding the incoming object by specifying `encoding` and/or `errors`. You could run into `TypeError` for anything other then [bytes-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) input or see decoding related failures: `UnicodeDecodeError`. This behavior of `str` is described in the following paragraph of its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> If at least one of encoding or errors is given, object should be a bytes-like object (e.g. `bytes` or `bytearray`). In this case, if object is a `bytes` (or `bytearray`) object, then `str(bytes, encoding, errors)` is equivalent to `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`. Otherwise, the bytes object underlying the buffer object is obtained before calling `bytes.decode()`.