# TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, bitmex

When I try running this line in python, using the Bitmex Rest API

```
qty2 = self.client.Position.Position_get(json.dumps({'symbol': 'XBTUSD'}),json.dumps({'currentQty'})).result()
```

I get this error

```
File "c:/Users/User2/sample_market_maker/SAMPLE/botv2.py", line 113, in place_orders
qty2 = self.client.Position.Position_get(json.dumps({'symbol': 'XBTUSD'}),json.dumps({'currentQty'})).result()
File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

I have seen [How to JSON serialize sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/how-to-json-serialize-sets). It shows a similar problem with an example but I am not sure how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Judging by the name, shouldn't `currentQty` have a quantity value, therefore making it a dict instead?

Comment: yeah i wanted to get the current qty value from the dict for that symbol and assign that value to qty2

Comment: this is the api docs https://www.bitmex.com/api/explorer/#!/Position/Position_get