# How to JSONL serialize sets in YAML style?

Tags: python, json, set, yaml, jsonlines

There are the three well-known format:

- [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
- [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/)
- [YAML](https://yaml.org/)

It is well-known, that

- [JSON can not handle Python sets without custom encoders/decoders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/how-to-json-serialize-sets/8230373#8230373).
- [YAML 1.2 is strict superset of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726802/what-is-the-difference-between-yaml-and-json/1729545#1729545)
- JSONL is JSON written in one line

I want to serialize (and unserialize) Python set (maybe other object as well) into one line (**JSON or YAML does not matter**), just like JSONL + custom encoder/decoder would do, but in a way that is **human readable** (like `repr()` in Python, **see example below**) (and possibly compliant with YAML). I would also like to keep all other functionalities and avoid [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/how-to-json-serialize-sets/59770802#59770802).

Do I have to write my own custom encoder or there are some better/existing solution? (e.g. parameter to yaml.dump() to do it in one line) What would be the most robust way to implement the example below?

E.g.:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, {'say', 'knights', 'ni', 'who'}, {'key': 'value'}, 3.14]
data_dumped = dump(data, ...)  # Magic dump function
print(data_dumped)
[1, 2, 3, !!set {knights: null, ni: null, say: null, who: null}, {"key": "value"}, 3.14]
data_loaded = load(data_dumped, ...)  # Magic load function
assert data == data_loaded
```

**UPDATE**: I have linked answers showcasing monkey patched `JSONEncoder` making `set()` (and other types) serializable using `pickle`, which is not human readable, therefore they do not answer this question. If these kinds of answers were good without modification, this question would be duplicate to the cited ones.

Comment: Have you checked-out my answer to [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder)

Comment: The most distinctive part of this question is that the serialized output MUST be human readable as  e.g. repr() in Python. Your suggested question/answer does not fulfill this requirement (it uses escaped pickled stuff, like the other linked answers). However, they are nice patches to the Encoder/Decoder framework, which could be improved to be human readable. Since it involves monkey patching, the answer below is better for the current question, even though it is YAML, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "YAML printed in one line" format similar to JSONL is called "inline syntax" and is achievable with `default_flow_style=True`, however, [this is very badly documented](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). The result is not JSON, but still standard compliant and does not require custom encoder/decoder.

See the example:

```
from yaml import dump, load
data = [1, 2, 3, {'say', 'knights', 'ni', 'who'}, {'key': 'value'}, 3.14]
data_dumped = dump(data, default_flow_style=True)
print(data_dumped)
[1, 2, 3, !!set {knights: null, ni: null, say: null, who: null}, {"key": "value"}, 3.14]
data_loaded = load(data_dumped)
assert data == data_loaded
```