# convert the dictionary with set to json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

i have a dictionary, print statement gives me this result
`{u'Cosmetics wholesaler': [set(['Famous', 85.94406247138977])], u'Mortuary': [set([80.53020238876343, 'Red']), set([57.67210125923157, 'Swordfish'])]}`

this is what gives me this dict with set appended

```
                if x[itm] not in dict.keys():
                    dict[x[itm]] = []
                dd = {x['Input Tag'], x['crank-' + itmSplit[1]]}
                dict[x[itm]].append(dd)
```

I want to dump this to json but after using json.dumps, its giving this error

raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/how-to-json-serialize-sets Looks pretty similar to what you are facing.

Comment: how do you create this dict in the first place with these one-element sets? values are list with one-element set, the element being 2-element list

Comment: I tried the approach but it isnt working.

Comment: in the example there is one missing opening [, but anyway - why so many square and curly braces?

Comment: dict[x[itm]].append(list(dd))