# object of type set is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i'm trying to pass the below list to ajax response but i'm getting below error

```
remove_duplicates = [{**l[0], 'record_id': set([x['record_id'] for x in l])} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=func), key=func)]
```

i'm using set to remove the duplicate record ids

```
list_of_dicts = [{'f_note':'text','record_id':{4691}},{'f_note':'sample','record_id':{4692}}]

return jsonify(list_of_dicts )
```

object of type set is not JSON serializable

please suggest me with the better option.

Comment: why do you need the set, e.g. `{4691}` in the first place? suggest me better option - use different data structure if necessary or just single int value.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230373/10217732) will help you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating your list of dicts your inner value of {4691} is actually a set not a dict.

https://realpython.com/python-sets/

Try this instead:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'f_note':'text','record_id': 4691},{'f_note':'sample','record_id': 4692}]

return jsonify(list_of_dicts)
```

See the error you encountered isolated

```
import json
test = {5565}

json.dumps(test)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

To keep the set functionaility you can cast it back to a list

```
remove_duplicates = [{**l[0], 'record_id': list(set([x['record_id'] for x in l]))} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=func), key=func)]
```

Comment: i'm using the set to remove duplicates...so I'm getting value like this {4961}.

Comment: Then cast it back to a list before you attempt to dump via JSON. This should solve your issue. 

    remove_duplicates = [{**l[0], 'record_id': list(set([x['record_id'] for x in l]))} if len(l:=list(v)) > 1 else l[0] for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=func), key=func)]