# Using javascript to parse Set stringified by a python script

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, set

I have a python script that spews a *stringified* Set of strings:

```js
let mySet = "{\"apple\",\"pear\",\"berry\"}"
```

How can I parse it back into a Set using javascript?

I tried:

```js
eval(mySet)
```

```js
new Set(mySet)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a literal representation of sets, so there's no built-in parser.

Comment: Can you change the Python code? You can use `json.dumps(list(mySet))`. In JavaScript, you can then use `new Set(JSON.parse(json))`

Comment: this is ugly, but works: `mySet.slice(1, -1).split()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to JSON serialize sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/how-to-json-serialize-sets)

Comment: and then (in JavaScript): `set = new Set(JSON.parse(python_set_as_list))`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for pointing it out. I ended up modifying my panda dataframe for the column containing Sets to Lists

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      let str = '{\\"apple\\",\\"pear\\",\\"berry\\"}';
      let arr = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]*/g).filter((item) => item);
      const newset = new Set([...arr]);
      console.log(newset);
```

Comment: that wouldn't be very robust as it won't work if the string inside the Set contains number or special chars

Comment: @asiera Yeah but, I think it can be easly adapted changing the expression, `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]` for example.