# Convert dynamic python object to json

Tags: python, json

I need to know how to convert a dynamic python object into JSON.  The object must be able to have multiple levels object child objects.  For example:

```
class C(): pass
class D(): pass

c = C()
c.dynProperty1 = "something"
c.dynProperty2 = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }
c.d = D()
c.d.dynProperty3 = "d.something"

# ... convert c to json ...
```

I tried this code:

```
import json
 
class C(): pass
class D(): pass
 
c = C()
c.what = "now?"
c.now = "what?"
c.d = D()
c.d.what = "d.what"
 
json.dumps(c.__dict__)
```

but I got an error that says `TypeError: <__main__.D instance at 0x99237ec> is not JSON serializable`.

How can I make it so that any sub-objects that are classes are automatically serialized using their `__dict__`?

Comment: except for the dynamic element--I don't know what properties might be added to the object before it is serialized into json.

Comment: You'll notice the solution of the duplicate works in your case, too.

Comment: @phihag: thanks for pointing that out.  It helped me realize there was more to my question than I thought (see updated question).

Comment: Then you should probably ask a new question. Pay special notice not to include invalid example code. For example, you want `class C(object): pass`. I added an answer that should solve your problem.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer.  I think that should do the trick.  However, I'm a little confused.  I don't see how "class C(): pass" is invalid code.  Am I missing something?  I am fairly new to Python.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was totally wrong. `class C(): pass` is of course *valid*, but it creates an old-style class (just like `class C: pass` would) in Python 2.x. old-style classes are strange beasts. By inheriting from `object`, you get the saner new-style behaviour.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Specify the `default=` parameter <sup>([doc](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump))</sup>:

```
json.dumps(c, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Comment: One of my object's attributes is a datetime and i'm having `'AttributeError' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: Same problem when an attribute is a set.

Comment: @arun For a set, you'd use a different method. If you expect both objects and set, use a helper function instead of a lambda, test for `isinstance(o, set)` and then return something like `list(o)`.

Comment: This one workds better than `json.dumps(c.__dict__)`, why?

Comment: @soulmachine your code just dumps a dictionary, whose values (and values of values, recursively) may still be Python objects that have no JSON representation. The code in this answer uses the object's `__dict__` for all those problematic objects, recursively.

Comment: @soulmachine From the Python3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump): *If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a TypeError. If not specified, TypeError is raised.*

Comment: what's `o` object?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari `o` is the argument of the callback function. This callback function gets called for objects that can't be serialized by `json.dumps`, i.e. anything but `int`/`float`/`bool`/`str`/`dict`/`list`/`None`.

Answer (score 16):

```
json.dumps(c.__dict__)
```

That will give you a generic JSON object, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: After looking into phihag's comment, I did some further testing and realized that this solution does not work in all cases...updating question...

Comment: That works for me as well.

Answer (score 9):

Try using this package [python-jsonpickle](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle)

> Python library for serializing any arbitrary object graph into JSON. It can take almost any Python object and turn the object into JSON. Additionally, it can reconstitute the object back into Python.

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` expects a dictonary as a parameter. For an instance `c`, the attribute `c.__dict__` is a dictionary mapping  attribute  names to the corresponding objects.