# Best way to save objects to text files in python?

Tags: python, parsing, serialization, encoding

I am writing a simple artificial neural net in python. I need to be able to save all of the data for a given net into a text file. Specifically, I need to save a list of nodes with the following properties:
name, layer number, delta value, connection weights

Right now, I've created my own data format. It looks like this:

```
nodeName:layer,delta,connectionWeights;
```

e.g.

```
a:1,.5,b-.5#c-.7;b:1,.75,c-.3#d-.4;c:2,.3,a-12#b-.4
```

It's actually fairly easy to create this data from an object and parse it to create an object from the data. However, the code is ugly and very specific to the format I've created. For context, here is the code I've written to parse:

```
   def readInput(self, datafile):
        f = open(datafile, 'r')
        DNAstring = f.read()
        f.close()
        #first, parse each node
        allNodes = DNAstring.split(";")
        for nodey in allNodes:
            n = nodey.partition(":") #partition separates node name from its data
            name = n[0]
            data = n[2].split(",") #each data element is separated by a comma
            layer = data[0]
            delta = data[1]
            connections = {}
            connectionList = data[2].split("#") #each connection is delimited by '#'
            for c in connectionList:
                x = c.partition("-")
                name = x[0]
                weight = x[2]
                connections.update({name:weight})
                print("updating connection with ", name, weight)
            #now we have all the data for a node, create a node object
            n = Node(name, layer, delta, connections)
            self.nodes.update({name:n})
```

My question is this: is there an easier way to go about this process? It seems to me like there must be an easier solution than creating a new data format and parsing function each time one wants to save an object to a text file.
Should I try to use an existing format like XML or JSON to make my code more understandable/modifiable? How would I go about doing this in python?

Thanks

Comment: Ref. [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) modules - or any other existing library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408647/convert-dynamic-python-object-to-json

Comment: JSON is good, avoid pickle (very slow and not cross-portable to other languages).

Comment: @HughBothwell: Whether to use `cPickle` or `json` depends on the task.  Pickle could be used to serialize a complex object to be read by the same Python program e.g., see `multiprocessing` module (and it is not very slow if you compare its C implementation against stdlib's json C implementation). `json` has wider application domain: human-readable, simple, has libraries in many programming languages, good mapping of json types to basic data structures (list, dict, Unicode string, numbers). It is used for a general data exchange between programs e.g., javascript in your browser and a server.

Comment: Data serialization speed comparison: http://www.benfrederickson.com/2014/02/12/dont-pickle-your-data.html