# simplejson.dumps(dict) throws "not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serializable, simplejson

I have a Python dictionary where the keys are strings, and values are list of MyObject objects.
If I execute

```
simplejson.dumps(dict)
```

it throws "MyObject not JSON serializable".

How can I avoid this exception, and how can I make MyObject serializable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458450/python-serializable-objects-json

Comment: @Johnsyweb i see the linked solution, but it helps a little. For me it doesn't work (it throws an exception while executing of query in BigTable).

Answer (score 8):

### Proper Answer

In order to make your `MyObject` serializable, you need to implement a method that you can reference on `dumps`. For example:

```
class MyObject:
    #    ...
    #    MyObject has 3 properties: name (a string), number (an int), and parent (a MyObject)
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(obj):
        return {
            "name":   obj.name,
            "number": obj.number,
            "parent": obj.parent
        }

    #    ...

simplejson.dumps(myObjInstance, default=MyObject.serialize)
```

The cool thing is that `dumps` will, like every other JSON-serializable object, call the serialization method recursively. That is, `obj.parent` will get serialized as well, without any further action from you.

### Golf'd Version

If all you want to do is 1-1 map instance variable names to their respective values, you can use some built-in Python magic. Whenever you want to serialize a more complex object (again, only using a 1-1 variable-value map), just call this line:

```
simplejson.dumps(anyObj, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)
```

For the given instance of `MyObject`, it will behave identically to the aforementioned `serialize` method.

Comment: consider `operator.attrgetter('__dict__')` instead of using a lambda.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination could you indicate why we should prefer that over a lambda?

Comment: @Stew: `operator.attrgetter()` is implemented in C;  the `lambda` version will need to create new call frames, execute python bytecodes, and altogether do a bunch of work.  When there's no concise, built in way to do it, a `lambda` is fine, but when there's something as concise and exact as the members of the `operator` module are available, those are better.