# Iterate over object attributes in python

Tags: python, oop, attributes, iteration

I have a python object with several attributes and methods.  I want to iterate over object attributes.

```
class my_python_obj(object):
    attr1='a'
    attr2='b'
    attr3='c'

    def method1(self, etc, etc):
        #Statements
```

I want to generate a dictionary containing all of the objects attributes and their current values, but I want to do it in a dynamic way (so if later I add another attribute I don't have to remember to update my function as well).

In php variables can be used as keys, but objects in python are unsuscriptable and if I use the dot notation for this it creates a new attribute with the name of my var, which is not my intent.

Just to make things clearer:

```
def to_dict(self):
    '''this is what I already have'''
    d={}
    d["attr1"]= self.attr1
    d["attr2"]= self.attr2
    d["attr3"]= self.attr3
    return d
```

·

```
def to_dict(self):
    '''this is what I want to do'''
    d={}
    for v in my_python_obj.attributes:
        d[v] = self.v
    return d
```

Update:
With attributes I mean only the variables of this object, not the methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251692/how-to-enumerate-an-objects-properties-in-python Might be of some help.

Comment: @sean In particular, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1251789/4203 is the way to go; you'd use the optional `predicate` argument to pass a callable that would filter out (bound?) functions (that gets rid of the methods).

Comment: Per sean, does this answer your question? [How to enumerate an object's properties in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251692/how-to-enumerate-an-objects-properties-in-python)

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Assuming you have a class such as

```
>>> class Cls(object):
...     foo = 1
...     bar = 'hello'
...     def func(self):
...         return 'call me'
...
>>> obj = Cls()
```

calling `dir` on the object gives you back all the attributes of that object, including python special attributes. Although some object attributes are callable, such as methods.

```
>>> dir(obj)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bar', 'foo', 'func']
```

You can always filter out the special methods by using a list comprehension.

```
>>> [a for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('__')]
['bar', 'foo', 'func']
```

or if you prefer map/filters.

```
>>> filter(lambda a: not a.startswith('__'), dir(obj))
['bar', 'foo', 'func']
```

If you want to filter out the methods, you can use the builtin `callable` as a check.

```
>>> [a for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(obj, a))]
['bar', 'foo']
```

You could also inspect the difference between your class and its instance object using.

```
>>> set(dir(Cls)) - set(dir(object))
set(['__module__', 'bar', 'func', '__dict__', 'foo', '__weakref__'])
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, I wouldn't even suggest it, but if you're going to, at least provide the caveat.

Comment: This seems straightforward. What do you mean with caveat? What could go wrong?

Comment: dir() will also list methods. I only want to list variables

Comment: @Pablo methods are also objects, but they're callable so you could exclude any callable objects. I will update the example.

Comment: @Meitham @Pablo What's wrong is mainly that you shouldn't need to do this. Which attributes you're interested in should be *inclusive* not *exclusive*. As you've already seen, you're including methods, and any attempt to exclude them will be flawed, because they're going to involve nasty things like `callable` or `types.MethodType`. What happens if I add an attribute called "_foo" that stores some intermediate result, or internal data structure? What happens if I just harmlessly add an attribute to the class, a `name`, say, and now all of a sudden it gets included.

Comment: @Julian the code above will pick both `_foo` and `name` because they are now attributes of the object. If you don't want to include them you can exclude them in the list comprehension condition. The code above is a common python idiom and popular way of introspecting python objects.

Comment: not callable is not working.. perhaps @Julian is right and I shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @Meitham That was the point, that it'd include them, and you'd specifically need to go out of your way to exclude them :). Anyways, I can chalk this up to a difference in philosophies, but IMHO good Python code never needs to do this. You use containers, and explicitly declare what you want to include.

@Pablo I didn't say it wouldn't appear to work :), as given, what @Meitham posted (including `callable` certainly should work).

Comment: Actually obj.__dict__ is (probably) better for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, `__dict__` is an implementation detail. Some objects don't even have one, like objects with `__slots__` but still can respond to `dir`. Neither is ideal though, since `dir` can also [lie](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: I don't know why SO isn't letting me edit that last comment, but now that you've changed your comment to be suggesting using `obj.__dict__`, my comment was discouraging it :).

Comment: @Pablo callable was not working because I had it wrong. Apologies. I was trying callable(k) where k is just the string. I should have said callable(the_method) which is getattr(obj,k) I have fixed that in my answer now. Apologies again if I have confused you.

Comment: @Julian `dir()` only "lies" when passed metaclasses (an extreme edge case) _or_ classes with attributes decorated by [`@DynamicClassAttribute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.DynamicClassAttribute) (another extreme edge case). In both cases, calling the `dirs()` wrapper `inspect.getmembers()` solves this. For standard objects, however, this solution's list comprehension approach filtering out non-callables _absolutely_ suffices. That some Pythonistas would label it a "bad idea" baffles me, but... to each their own, I suppose?

Comment: You can also use `vars(obj)`, which return `__dict__`, instead of `dir(obj)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181165/911945

Comment: The filter object returns in the filter example. Make sure to put a list method in front of the filter.

Comment: @Julian If you are using `__slots__` with no dict why not just iterate through the slots themselves?

Answer (score 81):

in general put a `__iter__` method in your *class* and iterate through the object attributes or put this mixin class in your class.

```
class IterMixin(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for attr, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            yield attr, value
```

Your class:

```
>>> class YourClass(IterMixin): pass
...
>>> yc = YourClass()
>>> yc.one = range(15)
>>> yc.two = 'test'
>>> dict(yc)
{'one': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'two': 'test'}
```

Comment: this only works when `one` and `two` is defined after `yc = YourClass()`. The question asks about looping through the existing attris in `YourClass()`. Also, inheriting the `IterMixin` class may not always available as a solution.

Comment: `vars(yc)` gives the same result without having to inherit from another class.

Comment: My above comment isn't quite right; `vars(yc)` is almost the same, but the dictionary it gives you back is the instance's own `__dict__`, so modifying it will be reflected on the instance. This can lead to problems if you're not careful, so the above method might sometimes be better (though copying the dictionary is probably easier). Also, note that while the dictionary returned above isn't the instance's `__dict__`, the values are the same, so modifying any mutable values will still be reflected in the instance's attributes.

Answer (score 73):

As mentioned in some of the answers/comments already, Python objects already store a dictionary of their attributes (methods aren't included). This can be accessed as `__dict__`, but the better way is to use `vars` (the output is the same, though). Note that modifying this dictionary will modify the attributes on the instance! This can be useful, but also means you should be careful with how you use this dictionary. Here's a quick example:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, x=3, y=2, z=5):
        self.x = x
        self._y = y
        self.__z__ = z

    def f(self):
        pass

a = A()
print(vars(a))
# {'x': 3, '_y': 2, '__z__': 5}
# all of the attributes of `a` but no methods!

# note how the dictionary is always up-to-date
a.x = 10
print(vars(a))
# {'x': 10, '_y': 2, '__z__': 5}

# modifying the dictionary modifies the instance attribute
vars(a)["_y"] = 20
print(vars(a))
# {'x': 10, '_y': 20, '__z__': 5}
```

Using `dir(a)` is an odd, if not outright bad, approach to this problem. It's good if you really needed to iterate over all attributes *and methods* of the class (including the special methods like `__init__`). However, this doesn't seem to be what you want, and even the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637457/4880003) goes about this poorly by applying some brittle filtering to try to remove methods and leave just the attributes; you can see how this would fail for the class `A` defined above.

(using `__dict__` has been done in a couple of answers, but they all define unnecessary methods instead of using it directly. Only [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python#comment93597568_11637457)) suggests to use `vars`).

Comment: Something I haven't figured out with the vars() approach is how to handle the situation where the class A has a member that is another object whose type is a user-defined class B. vars(a) seems to call __repr__() on its member of type B. __repr__(), as I understand, is supposed to return a string. But when I call vars(a), it seems like it would make sense for this call to return a nested dict, instead of a dict with a string representation of B.

Comment: If you have `a.b` as some custom class `B` then `vars(a)["b"] is a.b`, as one would expect; nothing else would really make sense (think of `a.b` as syntactic sugar for `a.__dict__["b"]`). If you have `d = vars(a)` and call `repr(d)` then it will call `repr(d["b"])` as part of returning it's own repr-string as only class `B` really knows how it ought to be represented as a string.

Comment: I tried to use `vars()` on the svmem object returned by `psutil` and it failed, saying that `__dict__` is not a member of the object. `dir()` works though, and I can see in its output that `__dict__` is not there. `psutil` docs suggest using `._fields`. Just to note a case where `vars()` failed, although I liked the idea of using it.

Comment: @KadirA.Peker that's true, `__dict__` does need to be defined for this to work. The vast majority of non-built-in Python classes should have this, but for more performance-critical classes, they may define `__slots__` instead. Calling `dir` will always work, but you'll need to filter out the methods and things like `__doc__`. You could probably also do something like `{name: getattr(a, name) for name in a.__slots__}` for some object `a` that has `__slots__` defined instead of `__dict__`. (objects like tuples have neither `__dict__` nor `__slots__` though)

Answer (score 4):

Objects in python store their atributes (including functions) in a dict called `__dict__`. You can (but generally shouldn't) use this to access the attributes directly. If you just want a list, you can also call `dir(obj)`, which returns an iterable with all the attribute names, which you could then pass to `getattr`.

However, needing to do anything with the names of the variables is usually bad design. Why not keep them in a collection?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **values):
        self.special_values = values
```

You can then iterate over the keys with `for key in obj.special_values:`

Comment: Can you explain a little more how would I use the collection to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm not adding attributes to the object dynamically. The variables I have will stay the same for a long time, however I think it would be nice to be able to do something like what I intend to.

Answer (score 2):

```py
class SomeClass:
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_idx = 0
        self.items = ["x", "y", "z"]
            
    def next(self):
        if self.current_idx < len(self.items):
            self.current_idx += 1
            k = self.items[self.current_idx-1]
            return (k, getattr(self, k))
        else:
            raise StopIteration
            
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

then just call it as an iterable

```
s = SomeClass()
for k, v in s:
    print k, "=", v
```

Comment: This seems too complicated. If I have no choice, I would rather stick with what i'm doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.6

```
class SomeClass:

    def attr_list(self, should_print=False):

        items = self.__dict__.items()
        if should_print:
            [print(f"attribute: {k}    value: {v}") for k, v in items]

        return items
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your posts, so that also non-professional pythonists can benefit from your answers?

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer to this is that you shouldn't. If you want this type of thing either just use a dict, or you'll need to explicitly add attributes to some container. You can automate that by learning about decorators.

In particular, by the way, method1 in your example is just as good of an attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I know I shouldn't.. but it helps me understand how things work. I come from a php background and used to do this kind of things daily

Comment: You've convinced me. Keeping the to_dict() method updated is far more straightforward than any answer so far.

Comment: Are there any people left that will refrain from dogmatic advice. Dynamic programming will burn you if you're not careful, but the features are in the language to be used.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are here to answer questions not judge them.

Comment: That's not why I'm here, though maybe it's why others are; I'm here to try and help people write good programs, not mindlessly answer questions without concern for whether they're helping people move in that direction. Feel free to treat the site as you would like though.