# How to get names of all the variables defined in methods of a class

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.var1 = "some value"
        self.var2 = something
    def bar(self):
        var3 = some value
    def baz(self, var):
        var4 = some value
```

I want to print the names of all variables defined inside the methods, like:

```
setUp, bar, baz, var1, var2, var3, var4
```

I have tried using `locals(), vars(), globals()` but I am getting only the names of method and not variable names.

I also tried using `ast` module, but no success.

Comment: Is there any reason you really need this information?

Comment: By mistake, I have given some wrong variable names and now I want to verify them.. my script is quite large, so its difficult to manually search for all variable names

Comment: @abhayj Can't you declare the variables in `__init__`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, I cannot declare all the variables in __init__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.var1 = "some value"
        self.var2 = "something"
    def bar(self):
        var3 = "some value"
    def baz(self, var):
        var5 = 34


print Foo.setUp.__code__.co_varnames
print Foo.bar.__code__.co_varnames
print Foo.baz.__code__.co_varnames
Output:
('self',)
('self', 'var3')
('self', 'var', 'var5')




 #There are many more things in __code__ dict:
   # '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'co_argcount', 'co_cellvars', 'co_code', 'co_consts', 'co_filename', 'co_firstlineno', 'co_flags', 'co_freevars', 'co_lnotab', 'co_name', 'co_names', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_varnames']
```

Comment: Are there any more attributes like 'co_varnames' that I can access? it is giving all variable names except variable names in setUp function.

Comment: Thank you very much.. this link is very helpful

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to generate AST node. Then [`ast.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.parse) can be used to recursively iterate over the node and its` descendants. For each node you can check the type and then extract the correct attribute.

Below is an example that is working with your code but don't expect it to work as such with more complex files:

```
source = '''
class Foo(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.var1 = "some value"
        self.var2 = 1
    def bar(self):
        var3 = 2
    def baz(self, var):
        var4 = var
'''

import ast

def hack(source):
    root = ast.parse(source)

    for node in ast.walk(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name) and isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
            yield node.id
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            yield node.attr
        elif isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            yield node.name

print(list(hack(source)))
```

Output:

```
['setUp', 'bar', 'baz', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
```

Comment: It's pretty impressive! It's just a random question, but I wonder where did you learn all of these. Did you learn it by inspecting ast module on your own? or can you recommend me a good material?

Comment: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) is really good but nothing beats playing around with the shell.

Comment: For this source, "def reverse(str): return str[::-1]", I don't get "str". why?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet (not enough reputation), but this looks like a duplicate of [Iterate over object attributes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python).

Try this:

```
print([a for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(obj,a))])
```