# Django admin: how iterate over form attributes in ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use Django 1.11.10 and python 3.6; I need to iterate `form` values in admin. How to do that?

```
class ServerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Server

    def clean(self):
        setattr(self, 'field1', 'value1')
        setattr(self, 'field2', 'value2')



class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ServerForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        # this works
        # but how to iterate form?

        obj.field1 = form.field1
        obj.field2 = form.field2

        # AttributeError: 'ServerForm' object has no attribute 'items'
        for key, value in form.items():
            setattr(obj, key, value)

        super(ServerAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Why do you use `setattr` here for a *fixed* string as attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you are setting attributes on the form in the clean method:

```
class ServerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Server

    def clean(self):
        setattr(self, 'field1', 'value1')
        setattr(self, 'field2', 'value2')
```

If you set the attributes on the form's instance, then you won't have to do it in the `save_model` method:

```
def clean(self):
    setattr(self.instance, 'field1', 'value1')
    setattr(self.instance, 'field2', 'value2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through attributes of a `form` object would be the same as iterating through the attributes of any other python object. Use `dir()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637457/1841522)