# Listing object attributes filtered by Descriptor type

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, attributes, iteration

I would like to use a custom Descriptor for validation and (de)serialization purposes like so:

```
class MyProperty():
  def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
    self.value = None

  def __get__ (self, obj, owner_class):
    return self.value

class MyClass():
  foo = MyProperty()
  bar = MyProperty()

  def __init__(self):
    self.baz = True

  def list_my_properties(self):
    pass # TODO
```

I fail at writing `list_my_properties` such that it returns all properties that were declared as `MyProperty` (e.g. `foo` and `bar`), but not others (e.g. `baz`). After reading [Iterate over object attributes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python), this is what I tried so far:

```
for a, v in self.__dict__.items():
  print(a, isinstance(v, MyProperty))
# [no output]

for a in dir(self):
  print(a, isinstance(getattr(self, a), MyProperty))
# foo False
# bar False
# baz False
```

How can I list the object attributes filtered by Descriptor type?

**Update:**

Based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652995/948404) (thanks!), I ended up with this:

```
def list_my_properties (self):
    return [ field for field, value in self.__class__.__dict__.items()
            if isinstance(value, MyProperty) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` and `bar` are defined as class variables, so you won't find them in the instance's `__dict__`, but rather the instance's class's `__dict__`:

```
for a, v in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(v, MyProperty):
        print(a)
```

This outputs:

```
foo
bar
```