# Copying python properties by reference

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have a tricky python structure issue that I can't quite wrap my head around.

Reading in large files is being pulled out of our application code and into its own package. It used to be that one class, lets call it `Object`, would be used to access file properties, and be passed around our `Application`. So `Application` package would call `Object.datetime`, but now would have to call `Object.file_handler.datetime`. So I have a few options:

1. For every property in `FileHandler`, create a property in `Object` that just references the `file_handler` object. So in `Object` do:

   ```
   @property
   def datetime(self):
       return self.file_handler.datetime
   ```

   This looks really gross because there are dozens of properties/functions, and it's super tight coupling. This is our current solution.
2. Find a way to copy those functions/properties automatically. Something like:

   ```
   for property in self.file_handler:
       create self.property with value self.file_handler.property
   ```

   Due to the size of files this MUST be a reference and not a memory copy.
3. Go through the application and replace every call to `self.object.property` with `self.object.file_handler.property`. Since `Application` is production level code, this is a big ask. It could break other things that we haven't touched in a while (unit tests exist but they're not great).
4. Restructure everything. `FileHandler` must be in a different package, and I don't want to copy/paste the functionality into `Application`. I can't have `Object` extend `FileHandler` because `Object` represents `FileHandler` at one instance in time (it makes my head hurt; basically `Object` is an `Application` instance and there are multiple `Application`s run per `FileHandler` object; `FileHandler` objects are passed to `Application` through an iterator). I need `Object` because `FileHandler` can't implement `Application` features - they should have been two classes in the first place. If someone is interested in this let me know and I can provide more structural details, but I'm leaning towards a hacky one-off solution.

This is a software design problem that I can't seem to crack. I recognize that our code is fragile and not well designed/tested, but it is what it is (most of it predates me, and this isn't a Software Engineering team - mostly math/physics people). Does anyone have guidance? Option 2 is my favorite but I can't find code to make it work.

Comment: ". Due to the size of files this MUST be a reference and not a memory copy." python never implicitly creates copies, everything has reference semantics, and you have to explicitly copy objects to actually create a new object. In any case, you can trivially proxy attribute access to your `file_handle` object using `__getattr__`,

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question, it isn't multiple questions, the OP is proposing different *solutions* to their problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, option 2 is possible, but the only way I can think to do it is so kludgy that it probably wouldn't be worth it. You'd have to get all the attribute names of `self.file_handler` then filter them to exclude magic attributes like `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__class__`, etc. I like Juanpa's suggestion better.

Comment: Hey, your __getattr__ comment helped me google the right things and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python

Comment: I can't edit my comment above.... not used to StackOverflow 
juanpa and wjandrea are right, above is simple code for getting all functions/properties. The tricky part would be creating properties for Object on the fly; basically doing solution 3 but in an automated fashion. That would be the ideal. But I don't think it's possible....

I'll keep digging around. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @jaykus Oh, I think you misunderstood juanpa's comment. I'll write you an answer in a little while, if juanpa doesn't get there first :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define [`Object.__getattr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to delegate attribute access to `self.file_handler`, for attributes not found on `self`.

For example:

```
class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

class Object:
    def __init__(self, file_handler):
        self.file_handler = file_handler
        self.x = 'foobar'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.file_handler, name)

f = FileHandler('some_file')
obj = Object(f)
print(obj.x)  # -> foobar
print(obj.filename)  # -> some_file
print(obj.y)  # -> AttributeError: 'FileHandler' object has no attribute 'y'
```

For more details, see the documentation link above.

*Thanks to [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for suggesting this in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763781/copying-python-properties-by-reference/65784114#comment116274096_65763781).*

---

I might also add some handling to make the exception message clearer, like this:

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.file_handler, name)
        except AttributeError:
            # Provide a clearer exception message.
            cls = type(self).__name__
            fh = type(self.file_handler).__name__
            msg = f'Both {cls!r} object and {fh!r} object have no attribute {name!r}'
            raise AttributeError(msg) from None

...

print(obj.y)
# AttributeError: Both 'Object' object and 'FileHandler' object have no attribute 'y'
```