# Need to append elements of the list into the function

Tags: python

```
for top in [eye_patch,hat]:
    test1 = pa.test(top_type=pa.TopType.top)
```

This is the code I wrote but I need it to basically say

```
test1 = pa.test(top_type=pa.TopType.eye_patch)
```

after which it runs

```
test1 = pa.test(top_type=pa.TopType.hat)
```

how do I get it to do this?

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what your structure is as you have not provided a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). I suggest you follow the guides there as it will help others answer your questions. That all said, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python) might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not really clear exactly what you're trying to do, why you're trying to do it, or whether you *have a good reason* to do it. In particular: it is not clear what the `eye_patch` and `hat` variables should contain, or how you expect them to be related to `pa.TopType.eye_patch` and `pa.TopType.hat`. If you wanted them to be strings, then they need to be quoted in your example code. It's also not clear what `pa.TopType` **is** (an enumeration? An ordinary class? A module?) The linked duplicate will work as asked regardless, but could be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an object's attribute by it's name, you need to use the `getattr('name')` function and pass your function name as a string.

Your code would look like this:

```py
for top in [eye_patch,hat]:
    test1 = pa.test(top_type=getattr(pa.TopType, top.__name__)())
```

`top.__name__` is for getting the function name as a string to call it as an attribute.

Comment: wait, how do we know `top` is a function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry my bad, i misread the question. it would still work with an object

Comment: huh? What do you mean "with an object"? *Everything* is an object in Python. And this will only work with objects that have a `__name__` attribute that happens to return the strings `"eye_patch"` and `"hat"` (which even in the case of functions is not something you can be sure about in this situation wihtout more details)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that was what i meant, it would work with anything you pass in that list. i can still just presume that `eye_patch` and `hat` have that attribute, no matter what type they are

Comment: No, you absolutely *cannot presume that*, why do you believe you can?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because the question author did not specify that `eye_patch` and `hat` are not default objects or whatever else without default attributes

Comment: **`__name__`** is not a default attribute. Most objects do not have a `__name__` attribute.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok but for some reason the question author did not say anything bad about it. let us not continue arguing

Comment: I'm not arguing. I'm pointing out your answer is wrong for people who read it.

Comment: I had thought it would be better to just edit the post rather than argue; but then I realized that we cannot really make assumptions about why the original code has `[eye_patch, top]` in the list rather than `['eye_patch', 'top']`. The values with those names could be anything, and OP could have any number of ideas about how the values should relate to the attributes of `TopType`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you exactly want is:

```py
from pa import test, TopType

for top in [TopType.eye_patch, TopType.hat]:
    test1 = test(top_type=top)
```

or an alternative:

```py
from pa import test, TopType

for top in ['eye_patch', 'hat']:
    test1 = test(top_type=getattr(TopType, top))
```

but make sure that `eye_patch` and `hat` are both methods of the TopType.