# How to create a dataclass that handles nested dicts with different names?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am using the data from the League of Legends API to learn Python, JSON, and Data Classes.  Using `dacite`, I have created parent and child classes that allow access to the data using this syntax: `champs.data['Ahri']['key']`.  However, I wonder if there is a way to create a class that returns the keys as fields so one could access the data using this syntax: `champs.data.Ahri.key`.

Here is the working code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict

j1 = {'type': 'champion',
      'data': {'Aatrox': {'id': 'Aatrox', 'key': '266', 'name': 'Aatrox'},
      'Ahri': {'id': 'Ahri', 'key': '103', 'name': 'Ahri'}}}

@dataclass
class C:
    type: str
    data: dict

@dataclass
class P:
    type: str
    data: dict

champs = from_dict(data_class=P, data=j1)
champs.data['Ahri']['key']
```

Comment: is being able to do : `champions['Ahri'].key` close enough?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would probably leave/make `champions` a dictionary. Then access it like `champions['Ahri'].key`

Something like:

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Champion:
    id: str
    key: str
    name: str

j1 = {
    'type': 'champion',
    'data': {
        'Aatrox': {'id': 'Aatrox', 'key': '266', 'name': 'Aatrox'},
        'Ahri': {'id': 'Ahri', 'key': '103', 'name': 'Ahri'}
    }
}

champions = {
    champion["id"]: Champion(**champion)
    for champion in j1["data"].values()
}

print(champions['Ahri'].key)
```

resulting in `103`

However if you were really keen on `champions.Ahri.key` then you can implement Champions as an empty class and use `setattr()`

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Champion:
    id: str
    key: str
    name: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Champions:
    pass

j1 = {
    'type': 'champion',
    'data': {
        'Aatrox': {'id': 'Aatrox', 'key': '266', 'name': 'Aatrox'},
        'Ahri': {'id': 'Ahri', 'key': '103', 'name': 'Ahri'}
    }
}

champions = Champions()
for champion in j1["data"].values():
    setattr(champions, champion["id"], Champion(**champion))

print(champions.Ahri.key)
```

again giving you `103`

Note: The `@dataclass` decorator can likely be omitted from Champion().

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas.  To clarify, my goal is not to have just the key work in that syntax, but to have ALL the items work that way.  I do not think it is, without jumping through hoops, but I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can probably get - at least in a *safe* enough manner - is as [@JonSG suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71328347/10237506), using `champs.data['Ahri'].key`.

Here's a straightforward example using the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://github.com/rnag/dataclass-wizard). It doesn't do a *strict* type checking as I know `dacite` does.

Instead, it opts to do *implicit* type coercision where possible, which is useful in some cases; you can see an example of this below - `str` to annotated `int` in this case.

> Note: This example should work for Python 3.7+ with the included `__future__` import.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import fromdict


data = {
    'type': 'champion',
    'data': {
          'Aatrox': {'id': 'Aatrox', 'key': '266', 'name': 'Aatrox'},
          'Ahri': {'id': 'Ahri', 'key': '103', 'name': 'Ahri'},
    }
}


@dataclass
class P:
    type: str
    data: dict[str, Character]


@dataclass
class Character:
    id: str
    key: int
    name: str


champs = fromdict(P, data)

print(champs)
print(champs.data['Ahri'].key)
```

Output:

```
P(type='champion', data={'Aatrox': Character(id='Aatrox', key=266, name='Aatrox'), 'Ahri': Character(id='Ahri', key=103, name='Ahri')})
103
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to do this

```py
d = {
    "type": "champion",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {"id": "Aatrox", "key": "266", "name": "Aatrox"},
        "Ahri": {"id": "Ahri", "key": "103", "name": "Ahri"},
    },
}


def dict_to_class(d) -> object:
    if isinstance(d, dict):

        class C:
            pass

        for k, v in d.items():
            setattr(C, k, dict_to_class(v))
        return C
    else:
        return d


champ = dict_to_class(d)

print(champ.data.Ahri.key)
# 103
```

The key here is the `setatter` builtin method, which takes an object, a string, and some value, and creates an attribute (field) on that object, named according to the string and containing the value.

### Don't do this!

I must stress that there is almost never a good reason to do this. When dealing with JSON data of an unknown shape, the correct way to represent it **is** a `dict`.

If you do know the shape of the data, you should create a specialized `dataclass`, like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

d = {
    "type": "champion",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {"id": "Aatrox", "key": "266", "name": "Aatrox"},
        "Ahri": {"id": "Ahri", "key": "103", "name": "Ahri"},
    },
}

@dataclass
class Champion:
    id: str
    key: str
    name: str

champions = {name: Champion(**attributes) for name, attributes in d["data"].items()}

print(champions)
# {'Aatrox': Champion(id='Aatrox', key='266', name='Aatrox'), 'Ahri': Champion(id='Ahri', key='103', name='Ahri')}

print(champions["Aatrox"].key)
# 266
```

Answer (score 0):

The dacite docs have a section about [nested structures](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite#nested-structures) that is very close to what you want. The example they use, verbatim, is as follows:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: int


@dataclass
class B:
    a: A


data = {
    'a': {
        'x': 'test',
        'y': 1,
    }
}

result = from_dict(data_class=B, data=data)

assert result == B(a=A(x='test', y=1))
```

We can access fields at arbitrary depth as e.g. `result.a.x == 'test'`.

The critical difference between this and your data is that the dictionary under the `data` key has keys with arbitrary values (`Aatrox`, `Ahri`, etc.). dacite isn't set up to create new field names on the fly, so the best you're going to get is something like the latter part of @JonSG's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71328347/12162258), which uses `setattr` to dynamically build new fields.

Let's imagine how you would use this data for a moment, though. Probably you'd want a some point to be able to iterate over your champions in order to perform a filter/transform/etc. operation. It's possible to [iterate over fields in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637457/12162258), but you have to really dig into python internals, which means your code will be less readable/generally comprehensible.

Much better would be one of the following:

1. Preprocess `j1` into a shape that fits the structure you want to use, and then use dacite with a `dataclass` that fits the new structure. For example, maybe it makes sense to pull the values of the `data` dict out into a list.
2. Process in steps using dacite. For example, something like the following:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict


@dataclass
class TopLevel:
    type: str
    data: dict


j1 = {
    "type": "champion",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {"id": "Aatrox", "key": "266", "name": "Aatrox"},
        "Ahri": {"id": "Ahri", "key": "103", "name": "Ahri"},
    },
}

champions = from_dict(data_class=TopLevel, data=j1)
# champions.data is a dict of dicts

@dataclass
class Champion:
    id: str
    key: str
    name: str


# transform champions.data into a dict of Champions
for k, v in champions.data.items():
    champions.data[k] = from_dict(data_class=Champion, data=v)

# now, you can do interesting things like the following filter operation
start_with_a = [
    champ for champ in champions.data.values() if champ.name.lower().startswith("a")
]
print(start_with_a)
# [Champion(id='Aatrox', key='266', name='Aatrox'), Champion(id='Ahri', key='103', name='Ahri')]
```